# Purge in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, purge

I am trying to create a `purge` command. In my research so far, this command was created in a separate file, in a `commands` folder, but I would like to put the command in my main.js

However, the following error occurs:

> ReferenceError: args is not defined

My code so far looks like this:

```
else if (parts[0] === Prefix + 'purge') {
        console.log("purging messages")


        embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Success")
            .setColor(0x00AE86)
            .setFooter("Guardian", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian/src/avatar.png")
            .setThumbnail("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian/src/avatar.png")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setURL("https://github.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/tree/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian")
            .addField("Bot Messages Purged", "missing code here", false)
            .addField("User Pins Purged", "missing code here", false)
            .addField("User Messages Purged", "missing code here", false)
            .addField("Total Messages Purged", "missing code here", false)

        message.channel.send({ embed });

        const amount = parseInt(args[0]) + 1;

        if (isNaN(amount)) {
            return message.reply('that doesn\'t seem to be a valid number.');
        } else if (amount <= 1 || amount > 100) {
            return message.reply('you need to input a number between 1 and 99.');
        }

        message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            message.channel.send('there was an error trying to prune messages in this channel!');
        });
```

Comment: Please paste the code you've tried into your question so we can take a look.

Comment: im so confused on why this is not working, and there is an error whoch says: ReferenceError: args is not defined

Comment: It's [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) not args

Comment: so i should replace every args with arguments?

Answer (score -1):

You said `args is not defined` so just define args

```
   const args = message.content.slice(Prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
```

Paste this on top of `console.log("purging messages")`

If this helps remember to click the checkmark to mark next to the upvote

Comment: well that helped the error but it is not purging, it just gives me the embed

Comment: yeah no error, but the purge ain't working

Comment: i can't talk anymore I have to ge to bed

Comment: @MohidMushtaq  const args = message.content.slice(Prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

Maybe because you defined prefix as Prefix so change to that

Comment: no, Prefix is right I even looked up in my code, and i saw ```var Prefix = ('.');```

Comment: now i really have to go to sleep cya in some hours

Comment: @MohidMushtaq No I meant my code was
 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

Since you define prefix as var Prefix = ('.')

Change how you define args like:

 const args = message.content.slice(Prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
I edited my answer